# Access a launched OpenProject on a VirtualBox (CentOS 7) from a host machine (MacOS)

Tags: virtualbox, macos-catalina

I am using Mac OS as a host machine of a VirtualBox. I have installed CentOS 7 on VirtualBox following these [intsructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVqveyG8pFE&ab_channel=Kurmavathar), I then Installed OpenProject on this Centos 7 following these [instructions](https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/packaged/#centos-7--rhel-7) and configured it using following [this](https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/packaged/#initial-configuration). It worked just fine, I was able to launch OpenProject on the browser of CentOS 7 - See the screenshot below.

[image]

I want to access the launched OpenProject of the CentOS 7 (of the VirtualBox) from my host Mac OS (using a Chrome browser), thats my goal.

I used ifconfig on CentOS 7 and got the IP address as displayed on the below screenshot,

[image]

I then used this IP address on my Mac OS Chrome browser like this, see these two screenshots:

[image]
[image]

It did not work, and I do not know why, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll need to open up port 80 to allow Apache/Nginx to serve requests over HTTP. If you haven’t already done so, you can do this by enabling firewalld’s http service with the following command:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
```

If you plan to configure Apache to serve content over HTTPS, you will also want to open up port 443 by enabling the https service:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
```

Next, reload the firewall to put these new rules into effect:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

After the firewall reloads, you are ready to start the service and check the web server.

I found this solution in : [lien](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7)